# horizontal scrolling and vertical scrolling in site using mobile view only

Tags: wordpress, mobile, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling

i want display vertical scrolling only to my site when used to see mobile view.I want remove the horizontal scrolling to my site when i used to see in mobile.
i have long pages in mobile view vertical scrolling is not appearing.

help me.

Comment: You need to show us more code and be a little bit more specific with this issue as it's too broad to answer. I for one would need to see your project in order to see why or how things would be arranged to scroll as you need.

Comment: yes,this is my project www.peroxywhite.com when i used to view in mobile view is is not displaying vertical scrolling..i am simply testing as mobile by minimizing the browser.check my site...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can use `@media` query and `overflow-x` or `overflow-y` to control the scrollbars, so with that said you can combine this:

**CSS**

```
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  body {
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
}
```

Adjust the 480px to meet your specific needs. [**Here is a fiddle that shows this query working**](http://jsfiddle.net/sulfureous/zA2ZP/) when you resize the browser to lower than 480px you can see that the scrollbar comes back.

Let me know if this works for you. As you can see we have the `overflow` set to hidden on the body (as you have now) and with this `@media` query I can bring it back when the width is 480px or lower.

Comment: I briefly modified the code to explain more why and how this work... would you consider that this answered your question?

Comment: thank you brother it is working when i specify only overflow-x:hidden

Comment: Yes, that should work too because of your current setup, but being more explicit about it you can see this example working too in a very simple manner for others to study.

Comment: can write css styles seperately for mobile view to any site

Comment: the `@media` query doesn't specifically target mobile phones or tablets, etc. What it does is that it detects the `viewport` size (this is the size of the window of your browser) and you can set that to any size and any website. Here is another post of someone explaining with more detail how those work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619217/can-someone-please-explain-css-media-queries

Comment: can make styles in mobile view for plugin also

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34052/discussion-between-krishna-and-sulfureous)